# Tensorflow installation error in python 3.8

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, python-wheel

I tried installing tensorflow using the command `pip install tensorflow` it gave the error two error as:-

- ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
- ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Then I used the command `pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` which again gave a single error as:-

- ERROR: tensorflow_gpu-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Finally, I tried downloading its latest WHL file and used the command `pip install tensorflow_gpu-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` from the same directory, still, I am getting the error 'ERROR: tensorflow_gpu-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.' and it's not installing.

I am using python 3.8.5, most of the answers are old for this topic and instructed to downgrade python as tensorflow wasn't available for python 3.8 but now it's available but still, I am facing this issue. Please help.

Comment: what Python version are you using? (post output of `pip -V`)

Comment: What platform are you using? This sounds like you have 32-bit python which TensorFlow does not support, or are installing TensorFlow for the wrong CPU architecture.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20%5btensorflow%5d%20ERROR%3a%20Could%20not%20find%20a%20version%20that%20satisfies%20the%20requirement%20tensorflow%20%3afrom%20versions%3a%20none%22

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a virtual environment to make things easier. Can you try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
python3 -m venv /random/directory/to/save/virtual_env
source /random/directory/to/save/virtual_env/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: Can you please specify windows specific command or instructions.